# How do I list two elements per item in array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have several email addresses per user, and I want to give two options per each of those addresses; one is to send email directly, and another one is to send a message via a web form. But how do I enlist two `<li>` elements under a single `ngRepeated` element?

If I do:

```
<span ng-repeat="email in User.emails">
 <li><a ng-attr-href="mailto:{{ email }}">Email {{ email }}</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#/SendMessage?email={{ email }}">Send message to {{ email }}</a></li>
</span>
```

Then I'm breaking the HTML structure and semantics.

If I do:

```
 <li ng-repeat="email in User.emails"><a ng-attr-href="mailto:{{ email }}">Email {{ email }}</a></li>
 <li ng-repeat="email in User.emails"><a ng-href="#/SendMessage?email={{ email }}">Send message to {{ email }}</a></li>
```

Then the emails are not in order (because the preferred order is to give primary email address first).

So the ideal output, assuming your email addresses are `chuck.norris@example.org` and `chuck@example.com` (excluding the `hrefs` just to make reading more clear), would be:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="...">Email chuck.norris@example.org</a></li>
 <li><a href="...">Send message to chuck.norris@example.org</a></li>
 <li><a href="...">Email chuck@example.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="...">Send message to chuck@example.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I do this, without adding disallowed elements into a `<ul>`?

Comment: Does it have to be two li elements? could you not have the two links in a single li element?

Comment: or could you have a nested ul under each li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the structure the same you can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat and look for the **Special repeat start and end points** section